# How do I add caching for images used in my ASP.NET MVC web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, iis

I have read this http://madskristensen.net/post/add-expires-header-for-images and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661.aspx and other similar articles, who suggest to put this

```
<staticContent>
 <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
</staticContent>
```

But even after that the images are not fetched from cache and 200 ok response is sent, that is a request to the server is made. I want no request to be made for x  hours/days coz these image wont change for a long time.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 9):

The following configuration should cause browsers to cache your images for an entire year:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="public" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

You just need to make sure your images are being served as static file types. There is no way of forcing a browser to not send a request to the server ie; the user performs a hard fresh.

You can wrap the above configuration in a location node so as to only affect images that site in a certain path:

```
   <location path="Content">
            <system.webServer>
              <staticContent>
                <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
              </staticContent>
              <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Cache-Control" value="public" />
                </customHeaders>
              </httpProtocol>
            </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

The above configuration would add an HTTP cache header directive for all images hosted at http://www.example.com/Content/Images/*

You should create a configurable appsetting that is passed in to such images URI's as a query string parameter. This will allow you to clear all the clients to send a request the images from your server: (We want control over this as cached images can be problematic)

```
<img src="/Content/Images/MyImage.jpg?version=<%# Global.ImageVersion %>" />
```

More on caching headers (Cache-Control) here http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

I hope that helps!

Comment: What file does this code go into and where. I tried to add it to my web.config and it just gave errors